# Login page cannot be found on https URL in ASP.NET MVC - HTTP 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

On the development machine I am running an ASP.NET MVC application under Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and IISExpress.

Login page runs fine on `http` Url. (i.e., http://payroll.net:81/Home/login?ReturnUrl=%2f)

Login page cannot be found on `https` Url. (i.e., https://payroll.net/Home/login?ReturnUrl=%2f). HTTP 404 Error.

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

I've enabled `SSL` on my `Application Properties` as well as `Controller(Home)`. I've also configured the **bindings** in `applicationhost` file as:

```
<sites>
  <site name="Payroll" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Visual Studio Projects\Payroll\Payroll" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:81:payroll.net" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:payoll.net" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
```

Any *idea* why `https` is not loading the login page?

Comment: Have you set up the certificate bindings in http.sys ?

Comment: @HastaPasta Not sure about that. How to do that?  Maybe I need to mention that apart from the login view in the application, SSL is working on all other views in the application (i.e., Index, Create, Edit, Delete etc.,). Thank you for replying.

Comment: @HastaPasta For example, if I cut `/Home/login?ReturnUrl=%2f` portion from Url (`https://payroll.net/Home/login?ReturnUrl=%2f`) which then becomes `https://payroll.net`, application runs like a charm.

Comment: Does your action or controller have [RequireHttps]. If not can you add them and give it a try. Its weird that its not working for login page so you may want to force it. Some good reading here http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jun/18/A-dynamic-RequireSsl-Attribute-for-ASPNET-MVC

Comment: @HastaPasta. All the views (including login) are inside `Home` Controller and I have set `[RequireHttps`] on `Home` Controller and `SSL(https)` is working for all other views except the login.

Comment: just checking on your web.config form's authentication you have requireSSL to true right

Comment: @HastaPasta Yes. `requireSSL="true"` is set in web.config.